# Eloquent Relations With Multiple Columns

Tags: php, orm, eloquent, relational-database

So I have the following `match` table which contains the numbers of the teams that participated in that match. I want to set up a relationship with the `teams` which looks something like this:

Teams Table

```
| id | number |  name   |  etc  |
| 1  |  1234  | Example |  etc  |
| 2  |  2345  | Example |  etc  |

etc...
```

Matches Table

```
| id |  match  |  red1  | red2 | blue1 | blue2 |
| 1  |    1    |  1234  | 1710 |  673  | 2643  |
| 2  |    2    |  2345  | 1677 | 4366  | 246   |

etc...
```

I want to have something like `$this->match->where("match", "=", "2")->first()->teams();`.

I have tried using hasMany() but I can't seem to get to use the `red1, red2, blue1, blue3` columns.

What I have tried:

```
class Matches extends Model
{
    protected $table = "match_table";

    protected $fillable = [
        "match_id",
        "time",
        "bluescore",
        "redscore",
        "red1",
        "red2",
        "red3",
        "blue1",
        "blue2",
        "blue3",
    ];

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Teams", "number", ["red1", "red2", "blue1", "blue2"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was just looping through each column I wanted and then just returning a new `Collection` with the results in it.

```
public function teams()
{
    $result = [];

    foreach($this::$teamColumns as $column) {
        $result[] = $this->hasMany("App\Models\Teams", "number", $column)->first();
    }

    return new Collection($result);
}
```